# BeagleBone Black & Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everybody,

Does anybody know how complex of a process it is to get a Ubuntu, Kinect and ROS running on a BeagleBone Black? I would like to do this for my humanoid robot project.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183037/beaglebone-black-&-kinect/) by [buihaduong](https://answers.ros.org/users/19453/buihaduong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-04**:
https://roboticsclub.org/redmine/projects/quadrotor/wiki/Installing_ROS_and_the_Kinect_stack_on_the_Pandaboard

http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't bother. The BeagleBone Black doesn't have enough processing power to handle a Kinect.

Some of the newer, more powerful ARM boards such as the Odroid U3 can handle a Kinect or an ASUS Xtion fairly well.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3